# Gulp Browser-Sync Loop

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

Newbie to using Gulp and Browser-Sync and I seem to be stuck in an infinite loop when using browserSync.reload() with files stored on a network drive.

If I run the following code for files stored on my local machine it works perfectly fine, but if I run the code on files that are on the networked drive, the 'refresh' task keeps getting run over and over again with out me making any changes to files.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync');

 gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
 browserSync.init({
  open: 'external',
  host: 'test.dev',
  proxy: 'test.dev',
  port: 3000
 });
});

gulp.task('refresh', function () {
  browserSync.reload();
  // console.log('Refresh');
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('**/*.{php,inc,info}', { usePolling: true },['refresh']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

I found a few post that seem to have a similar issue, those were resolved by updating to the latest version of Browser Sync or using { usePolling: true } on the watch task but I have had no such luck.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: well, it really doesn't seem like there is any relation to browserSync, since it's the refresh task that's getting ran over and over, right?  Are you sure there are no files being automatically edited (like your .info files or something)?

Comment: It only happens when browserSync.reload() is the command in the task. If I comment that out and run the console.log() command it works as expected so I don't think anything like that is happening.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.  Actually, try updating your watch to look like this - gulp.watch('**/*.{php,inc,info}').on('change', browserSync.reload);

Comment: When I add in that line of the code the browser doesn't reload when a file changes.

Comment: looks like the comment was removing the first two asterisks from my blob.  Update the gulp.watch path with the on you have from above.  `gulp.watch('**/*.{php,inc,info}').on('change', browserSync.reload);`